# Check if class has an empty destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class like:

```
struct A {
public:
    A(int a, int c): a_(a+c), c_(a-c) { }
    A(const A& arg): a_(arg.a_), c_(arg.c_) { }
    int a_;
    char c_;
};
```

Objects of this class are located inside some dinamically allocated memory regions. During freeing of this memory regions A destructor is not supposed to be called. 
So I want to be sure that A destructor is really empty. For example if somebody will add `std::string s_;` member to the class A then it will be obviously a memory leak if destructor will not be called.

If there were no Constructor and Copy Constructor in A then I could add check:

```
 static_assert(std::is_trivial<A>::value)
```

But for class A it will fail.

So my question: Can I somehow check at compile time if destructor of such class is really empty and doesn't do any work?

Answer (score 10):

This is what [`std::is_trivially_destructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible) is for:

```
std::is_trivially_destructible<A>::value
```

Make sure to `#include <type_traits>`.